# jQuery: Update, by class, span tags when a particular radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

How can I update  tag class="able" when a particular radio button is selected?

Steps:
Page opens span class able is cleared.
Whenever radio1, radio2 or radio3 are selected:
If radio1 has been selected, span class="able" is updated with the value of input host1.
If radio2 has been selected, span class="able" is updated with the value of input host2.
If radio3 has been selected, span class="able" is updated with the value of input host3.

Thank you, in advance!

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery Update span by radio button selection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
    <input type="text" id="host1" value="Able">
    <input type="text" id="host2" value="Baker">
    <input type="text" id="host3" value="Charlie"><br>

    <label><input type="radio" name="radiogroup" value="yes" id="radio1" />Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radiogroup" value="no"  id="radio2" />No</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radiogroup" value="maybe" id="radio3" />Maybe</label>
    <br>

    </div>

    <span id="result1" class="able"> </span><br>
    <span id="result2" class="able"> </span><br>
    <span id="result3" class="able"> </span>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to add click events to your radio buttons, which onclick would change the value of the spans.

Something like:

```
$('#radio1').click(function(){$('span.able').html($('#host1').val());});
```

You could also make it more common:

```
$('input:radio').live('click',function(){
  var jThis = $(this), jText = $('#'+jThis.attr('text_id'));
  $('span.able').html(jText.val());
});
```

You would need to add an attribute "text_id" to the radio button to identify which text should be used for a given radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){

    var id = this.id.replace('radio', '');
    $('#result' + id).text($('#host' + id).val()); 

});
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2vC2/)**